# How to see where in the queue I am for a job on a cluster?

Tags: queue, cluster-computing, pbs, qsub

I am using a cluster computer to compute a "lmem" job. I submitted my job a day ago and while normally the job immediately begins running and I can monitor how long it has been running with `qstat`, this job remains in the queue.

I used `qstat -q` to see that

```
`Queue            Memory CPU Time Walltime Node  Run Que Lm  State
---------------- ------ -------- -------- ----  --- --- --  -----
lmem               --      --       --      --   36 235 --   E R
batch              --      --       --      --    8   0 --   E R
express             4gb    --    06:00:00   --   17   0 --   E R
test               --      --       --      --    0   0 --   D S
production         16gb    --       --      --   66 157 --   E R
route              --      --       --      --    0   0 --   E R`
```

Someone must have put in A LOT of lmem jobs. I was wondering if there was a way to see where on that list of 235 my job is in line?

Answer (score 1):

When using a scheduler like Moab or Maui, you can run a commands such as `checkjob -v` and `mdiag -p` (or have an admin do it for you) to see if the job has an advance/priority/job reservation, and how many jobs it has in front of it. The default ordering of `showq` will place jobs with a job reservation at or near the top of the Eligible/Idle list. If you're only using `pbs_sched`, then the order shown in a plain `qstat` is the order in which it will run, although that may not make it clear how *soon* it can run.